# Retrieving results in a faster way

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination

I am trying to fetch values for pagination.I need 20 records for every page.So based on page number,I am querying like mentioned below.I want the query to take minimum time while retrieving values

"page" contains the page number value at which I am currently present.

```
Select * FROM Table_A where Name Like lower('see%k%') 
ORDER BY Name OFFSET (page-1)*20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

I have seen offset is not good if we have lots of matching values,we will have to parse for lot of values when I am at final pages.Please suggest some better search query.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand wrote about this exact thing: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it the old way. Base it on these examples from products. Find first page:

```
SELECT TOP(@PageSize) ProductID, Description
FROM dbo.Products 
ORDER BY ProductID;
```

Then remember the last value returned, and request next page:

```
SELECT TOP(@PageSize) ProductID, Description
FROM dbo.Products 
WHERE ProductID > @LastProductID
ORDER BY ProductID;
```

Then to go back a page, remember the first value returned, and then something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT TOP(@PageSize) ProductID, Description
      FROM dbo.Products 
      WHERE ProductID < @FirstProductID
      ORDER BY ProductID DESC) AS SelectedProducts
ORDER BY ProductID;
```

That'll usually way outperform OFFSET and FETCH NEXT

Comment: Thanks for the idea.But,sometimes I can also go from 10th page to 2nd page.At a moment,I can go to any page from a set of consecutive 10 pages.This solution which you provided is valid only for current,pevious and next page.

Comment: Sure, but then you're back to slow.